# add class to a element if the parent element contains an element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

i have to add a class to a element(h2) on it's click event if the parent element(class="container") contains an element(class="sub-cat") inside it. [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/gSCQ7/5/)

```
$('.container h2').click(function(){
//alert('hi');
if($(this).has(".sub-cat")){
    $('.container h2').addClass(highlight);
}
else if () {
    $('.container h2').removeClass(highlight);
}
```

});

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when you use click then `this` referce to the h2 you clicked on, use `.parent()` to (or .closest('.container') and then use your look up:

http://jsfiddle.net/gSCQ7/7/

```
var highlight = "highlight";

$('.container h2').click(function(){
    var hasSubCategorys = $(this).parent().find(".sub-cat").length > 0;
    $(this)[hasSubCategorys  ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass'](highlight);
});
```

or if you want it more readable:

```
var highlight = "highlight";

$('.container h2').click(function(){
    var hasSubCategorys = $(this).parent().find(".sub-cat").length > 0;
    if(hasSubCategorys) {
        $(this).addClass(highlight);
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass(highlight);
    }
});
```

edit: http://jsfiddle.net/gSCQ7/10/ changed the CSS code to be more specific then `.container h2` vs `.hightlight`

Comment: the title(h2) is repeated twice in your link. please refer to class(.highlight) property to be added on h2

Comment: yeah, it is just to show that if you have a container that doesnt have a .sub-cat then it wont add a highlight class to h2 element. if its not what you want then please explain what you want your code to do. Because your current code is missing the variable `highlight` for example.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.container h2').click(function(){
    if ($(this).closest('.container').find('.sub-cat').length) {
        $(this).addClass('highlight');
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('highlight');
    }
});​
```

When the h2 element is clicked, use `closest()` to traverse up through the DOM tree and find the first parent element with class 'container', then use `find()` to traverse back down the DOM to find the element with class 'sub-cat'.  If the '.sub-cat' element is found (`length`), add 'highlight' class to the clicked h2, otherwise, remove 'highlight' class from the clicked h2.

[jQuery docs for Tree Traversal](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/)

Comment: can you add some explanation of why this is the answer

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if( $(this).parent().find(".sub-cat").length > 0 ) {
  ...
}
```

or

```
if( $(this).closest(".container").find(".sub-cat").length > 0 ) {
  ...
}
```